# How to delete folders every N minutes from comand line

Tags: bash

I am am trying to run the below command to delete tmp folders greater than 3 minutes using the below:

```
 find /tmp/tmp* -mmin +3 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

The above command fails.  Why?

```
find /tmp/tmp* -mmin +3 -exec rm -rf {} \;
find: `/tmp/tmpAJaHLX/crashes': No such file or directory
find: `/tmp/tmpbM5ac8/minidumps': No such file or directory
find: `/tmp/tmpbM5ac8/crashes/events': No such file or directory
find: `/tmp/tmpdQACdf/gmp': No such file or directory
find: `/tmp/tmpo1tbqu/thumbnails': No such file or directory
find: `/tmp/tmpW91Yel/extensions': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Why are you deleting random stuff from `/tmp`? Are you aware that `/tmp` holds running programs' temporary files? But anyway that's likely because you don't have permissions on those files / folders.

Comment: I am root and the proccess that creates those folders do not do cleanup.  Yes..I know what the tmp dir does and its used.

Comment: find could lists folder and file and it could be due to rm execution order

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing is likely a result of the `find` command's *traversal order*.

e.g. given a simple directory

```
$ find somedir
somedir
somedir/file
```

then

```
$ find somedir -exec rm -rfv {} \;
removed ‘somedir/file’
removed directory: ‘somedir’
find: `somedir': No such file or directory
```

You can force a depth-first traversal using the `-depth` option, i.e.

```
$ find somedir -depth -exec rm -rfv {} \;
removed ‘somedir/file’
removed directory: ‘somedir’
```

does not result in error.

Alternatively, you can use the simpler `find somedir -delete` which (as noted in the manual page) turns on the `-depth` option

```
-delete
       Delete files; true if removal succeeded.  If the removal failed,
       an  error message is issued.  If -delete fails, find's exit sta‐
       tus will be nonzero (when it eventually exits).  Use of  -delete
       automatically turns on the -depth option.
```

Comment: You can also suggest to setup a cron job, if the command needs  to be executed  every X minutes.